# Changing document format regardless of the document class!

Tags: margins, two-column, document-classes

Is there any way to change the format of a document such as single/double column, margins, etc regardless of the `documentclass` used?

I am using `iopart.cls` and it does not have a `twocolumn` option. how can I make it two column and adjust margins without changing the `documentclass`?

Comment: `iopart` is for journal submission: as such they've made a decision not to have two column format available. Be very cautious about altering the format.

Comment: The command `\twocolumn` is defined in the LaTeX kernel and not inside the documentclass.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, it's only for revising purpose. @Marco: Thank you, it actually worked the way I wanted, any ways to change the margins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to summarise what's already been said in the comments:

- You can use `\twocolumn` to enter two-column mode. When you issue the `\twocolumn` command, LaTeX will start a new page, and henceforth use two columns for the rest of the document.
- There's also the `multicol` package, which is a bit more powerful than the primitive `\twocolumn` command. For instance, `multicol` arranges that the columns on the final page will be of roughly equal length, and also allows customisation of vertical rules between columns.
- You can easily adjust margins using the `geometry` package. Putting `\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}` in your preamble should do the trick.